# To implement Rememberme functionality using Cookie Authenticator restlet

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, session-cookies, restlet

Code:

```
private CookieAuthenticator createCookieAuthenticator() {
CookieAuthenticator authenticator = new CookieAuthenticator(getContext(), "abc",
                "KeyXXX".getBytes()) {
            @Override
            protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {

                String uri = request.getResourceRef().getRemainingPart();
                if ((uri.startsWith("/angular")||(uri.startsWith(this.getLoginPath())
                        || uri.startsWith(this.getLogoutPath()) || (uri.startsWith("/checkLogin")))) {

                    if(uri.startsWith("/checkLogin")){

                        String rememberme=request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm()
                                .getFirstValue(Config.REMEMBERME);
                        if(null!=rememberme && rememberme.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            setMaxCookieAge(2147483647);
                        }else{
                            setMaxCookieAge(-1);
                        }               
                    }
                    return super.beforeHandle(request, response);
                } else { // All other urls
                    return CONTINUE;
                }
            }
authenticator.setLoginFormPath("/login.html");
        AccountVerifier verifier = new AccountVerifier();  
        authenticator.setVerifier(verifier);
        return authenticator;   

}
```

**setMaxCookieAge** set age variable in Cookie authenticator class.

But in case of multiple request coming from UI . **new instance of cookie authenticator** initialized which set max age =-1 . (Session Cookie)

This Cookieauthenticator restlet class  is used in server hosted in google app engine .

```
public class Servlet extends Application {

    private ChallengeAuthenticator authenticator;

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
this.authenticator = createCookieAuthenticator();
}
```

in appengine-web.xml 
threadsafe flag-false

On Changing threadsafe flag  to true : make only instance of cookie authenticator but making all request from different user - cookie age set to be latest value which is selected when checklogin request called.